# Allowing mixed (insecure) content on Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is it possible to enable insecure content explicitly for a site in Chrome?

It's possible in desktops by going into site settings and allowing "insecure content", but when I checked the same in Android, it only has one option called sound in site settings.

Use case: streaming m3u8 files and the browser keeps blocking them, I want to enable insecure content for phones as well.

Comment: Try pasting this in search bar `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and toggle settings followed by restarting it browser. If it doesn't help, type `Chrome://flags` (don't get put off by the warning) and search for `secure` and experiment

Answer (score 4):

I am copy-pasting [@beeshyams comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224891/enabling-mixed-content-on-chrome-android#comment292394_224891) as it worked for me.

> Try pasting this in the search bar `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and toggle settings followed by restarting its browser. If it doesn't help, type `chrome://flags` (don't get put off by the warning) and search for `secure` and experiment.

Comment: The above answer doens't work for me. Someone has another? I really need this